# regex search von Bibtex file to extract cite key and title in capture groups

Tags: regex

The problem I have is that i would like to extract only the cite key and the Title of an Bibtex library file using capture group.

My Data file looks like this.

@article{Wang2017,
author = {Wang, Yunsen and Kogan, Alexander},
file = {:/2017/2017{_}Designing Privacy-Preserving Blockchain based Accounting Information Systems.pdf:pdf},
keywords = {accounting information systems,blockchain,continuous auditing},
title = {{Designing Privacy-Preserving Blockchain based Accounting Information Systems}},
year = {2017}
}

For the extraction of the cite key I used the following regex:

@\w+{([\w:-]+)

For the extraction of the title I used the following regex:
title = {{(.*?)}}

Both work. But I'm not able to combine both into one regex command so that cite key is capture group 1 and title is capture group 2

You can find the example file and the already used regex command using the following link.

https://regex101.com/r/v4cIe6/1

My expected result would be one command to extract cite key and title at once and have it in different capture groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a negative lookahead is supported, you could repeat all the lines that do not start with title. If the line does, match it followed by space, `=`, space and `{{` and capture the title in capturing group 2

```
@\w+{([\w:-]+).*(?:\r?\n(?!title\b).*)*\ntitle = {{(.*?)}}
```

**Explanation**

- `@\w+{([\w:-]+)` The pattern to match the cite key
- `.*` Match any char except a newline non greedy
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\r?\n(?!title\b).*` Match a newline asserting the string does not start with title
- `)*` Close Non capturing group and repeat 0+ times
- `\r?\ntitle =` Match a newline, then `title =`
- `{{(.*?)}}` The pattern to match the title, capture in group 2 matching between `{{` and `}}`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SVNygR/1)